# Create Domain Error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

I am trying to define a new domain "rating_int" that I would be able to use in the table "Review". Anytime I try to execute this query, it returns this message:

ERROR:  column "rating_int" does not exist

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "rating_int" does not exist

SQL state: 42703

I followed the exact same code format as the [postgresql example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdomain.html) and I do not know why my code is returning an error.

```
CREATE DOMAIN rating_int AS INTEGER
CHECK(rating_int > 0 AND rating_int <=10);

CREATE TABLE Review
(
    paper_id INTEGER,
   rv_email VARCHAR(55)     NOT NULL,
   reccomendation TEXT,
   a_comments TEXT,
   c_comments TEXT,
   technical_merit rating_int,
   readability rating_int,
   orginality rating_int,
   relevance rating_int,
   PRIMARY KEY(paper_id, rv_email),
   FOREIGN KEY(paper_id) REFERENCES Paper
   ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY(rv_email) REFERENCES Reviewer
   ON DELETE SET NULL   ON UPDATE CASCADE
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `value`, not the name of the domain.  Like this:

```
CREATE DOMAIN rating_int AS INTEGER
    CONSTRAINT chk_rating_int CHECK (value > 0 AND value <= 10);
```

You don't actually need to give the constraint a name -- your error was `rating_int` instead of `value`.  So this works:

```
CREATE DOMAIN rating_int AS INTEGER
    CHECK (value > 0 AND value <= 10);
```

However, I think it is a good idea to give constraints names.

Also, you might want to make the type a `smallint` or `decimal(2)`, if you want to save on space.

Comment: Thanks, my query executed with no problems. Can I ask why am I expected to use `value` rather than the name of the domain?

Comment: @stargazer . . . That is how the syntax is defined.